# How to response with 400 if request body json is invalid in `express.js`

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I need my application to response with 400 instead of throw error if request body is invalid json

```js
import express from 'express'

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.json())
```

Comment: You shouldn't use 400 for that

Comment: @AluanHaddad What status code should I use?

Comment: [Node.js - Handle body-parser invalid JSON error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048642/node-js-handle-body-parser-invalid-json-error)

Comment: @AluanHaddad Why do you think 400 wouldn't be a good response to an invalid request? Seems right to me.

Comment: Actually, it seems 400 is the appropriate status code. Disregard what I said in my first comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use this custom middleware to parse the json

```
import express, { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express'

const ParseJson = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const errorHandler = (err: Error | null) => {
        if (err instanceof Error) {
            // Invalid Json

            res.status(400).json({
                errors: ['Invalid json'],
                data: {},
            })

            return
        }

        next()
    }

    express.json()(req, res, errorHandler)
}

export default ParseJson
```

And use it like this

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(ParseJson)
```